# Insert document with nested ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

I am trying to insert a document into my mongodb that looks like this:

```
_id : ObjectId(<id>)
players : {
    ObjectId(<id>) {
       entry : 'foo'
    }
}
```

However, I can't form JSON in node with an ObjectId as a key. What's the best practice for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names):

> Field names are strings.

So you can't use ObjectId's as keys, but you can use their string representation:

```
var playersObj = {};
playersObj[ObjectId()] = { entry : 'foo' }; // this will stringify the ObjectId

var document = {
  _id     : ObjectId(),
  players : playersObj
};
```

Comment: I'd also like to point out that if you're using `playerId`s anyway, it might make sense to store the `player` objects in a separate collection (and only store ids in the model you've shared) so you can avoid having to manage nested documents. This, of course, depends on your particular use case, but generally this is a more flexible manner of storing/managing your documents.